# c pipe: Program just stop before wait(NULL);

Tags: c, pipe

The program can read all the data from the pipe. However, the program just stop. It cannot continue to process. I think it stop in the child process.

```
//I created two pipe before fork (fd[0] and fd[1]).
//child process
if(pid == 0){
    close(fd[a][1]);
    buf[6];
    int i;
    while ((i = read(fd[a][0], buf, 6)) > 0) {
        printf("%s", buf);     
    }
    close(fd[a][0]);
exit(0); 
}

//parent process
write(fd[a][1], "12", 2);
write(fd[a][1], "14", 2);
write(fd[a][1], "15", 2);
write(fd[b][1], "12", 2);
write(fd[b][1], "14", 2);
write(fd[b][1], "15", 2);
printf("done!\n");
close(fd[0][1]);
close(fd[1][1]);
wait(NULL);
printf("Really done!!!\n");
...                      // The program cannot run after wait(NULL);

--output--
121415done
```

Comment: Can you make a complete example? See http://sscce.org/

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg I have provided more detail of my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are issuing `read` in a while loop, effectively blocking yourself until something goes wrong. If you need to read `6` characters, this is how you would write the child process:

```
char buf[7];
int left = 6;
int so_far = 0;   // instead of so_far, (6 - left) could also be used
while (left > 0)
     int num_read = read(fd[0][0], buf + so_far, left);
     left -= num_read;
     so_far += num_read;
}
buf[so_far] = '\0';
printf("%s\n", buf);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I edited my code. The problem can keep processing after wait(NULL);. However, it got want output like following (child only get the first write. And it got wrong data).

     2021

     done!

     Really done!!!

Comment: Thank you so much. I solved the problem. Your code is perfect. Actually, I made some stupid mistakes so that the program cannot run in last time.

Comment: I still have a little problem. How can I make a break line in the buf?

Comment: You mean a `'\n'`? Just where when you want: `buf[so_far] = '\n';` and then `++so_far`, but not `--left`. This is because you are generating data, so `so_far` goes ahead, but you still expect the same amount of data that is `left`

Comment: Don't forget to take an extra char in your buffer for the ending `'\0'` if you are planning on using the buffer as a string (for example for printing with `%s`

Answer (score 0):

The two processes are caught in a deadlock, each one waiting for the other.
You want the child process to stop processing, but it waits for the parent process, because it doesn't "know" that the parent will not send any more data.
To make it clear to the child, close the writing end of the pipe:

```
write(fd[0][1], "12", 2);
write(fd[0][1], "14", 2);
write(fd[0][1], "15", 2);
printf("done!\n");
close(fd[0][1]);
wait(NULL);
```

Comment: It is already included close(fd[0][1]) in my code. However, i didn't show it out. Sorry.....

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you haven't closed the "write" fd in the child process, hence the call to `read` will block, which in turn blocks `wait` in the parent process.

Also: if you've omitted something from your question, as in the response to @anatolyg's answer, you should edit the question. It's the same answer I would have given at first.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I already add close fd in the child process. However, the problem still not solve.

Comment: @EricTang - you need to `close(fd[1])` or `[a][1]` (?) - the *write* file descriptor - in the child process *before* you start reading.

Comment: Oh, sorry I missed it. But the problem still here.